# Obj-C enum "Incompatible Types in initialization"

Tags: objective-c, initialization, enums, incompatibility

I'm having a problem with enum type initialization that appears to be simple to solve but I haven't figured out how to do it.
Suppose I declare the following enum type:

```
typedef enum NXSoundType {
    NXSoundTypeNone,
    NXSoundTypeEffect,
    NXSoundTypeBackgroundMusic
} NXSoundType;
```

I declare a convenience method for returning one of the NXSoundType enum types given a NSString object like this (NOTE: NXSound is an object that contains a NXSoundType attribute named "type"):

```
- (NXSoundType)nxSoundTypeFromIdentifier:(NSString*)nxSoundIdentifier {
    NXSoundType type = NXSoundTypeNone;

    for (NXSound *nxSound in self.nxSounds) {
        if ([nxSound.identifier isEqualToString:nxSoundIdentifier]) {
            type = nxSound.type;
        }
    }    
    return type;
}
```

So far, so well. But the following call is not working:

```
NXSoundType type = [self nxSoundTypeFromIdentifier:@"kNXTargetGameSoundIdEffectTic"];
```

What's wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? You mention an error message in the title, but you didn't say where the error is occurring. Also, what's the definition of the `NXSound` class?

Comment: Also note if you're getting any compile warnings.

Comment: Sorry if my question seems ambiguous or isn't explanatory enough. The problem occurs in the last code listing: "NXSoundType type = [self nxSoundTypeFromIdentifier:@"kNXTargetGameSoundIdEffectTic"];". The compiler shows the following error message: "Incompatible types in initialization". I'm not getting any compiler warnings. The convenience method compiles successfully, the error occurs only in the method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Despite the compiler error message, the problem was not related to wrong enum type declaration/initialization. The problem was that the method

```
- (NXSoundType)nxSoundTypeFromIdentifier:(NSString*)nxSoundIdentifier;
```

was defined as a private method in a base-class and was been called by a sub-class. In this way,  due to the Obj-C dynamic nature, it was expected to return an `id` which cannot be assigned to the `NXSoundType` enum (only to objects). A simple cast removed the problem, the solution was to change the method call to:

```
NXSoundType type = (NXSoundType)[self nxSoundTypeFromIdentifier:@"kNXTargetGameSoundIdEffectTic"];
```

Appreciate all replies and sorry for any confusion. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: lol don't forget to accept your answer.  glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using just:

```
typedef enum {
    NXSoundTypeNone,
    NXSoundTypeEffect,
    NXSoundTypeBackgroundMusic
} NXSoundType;
```

and see if that helps.  having the typedef and name be the same might be confusing Obj-C compiler [like this person's question.](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2006/Aug/msg00082.html)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. I changed the enum declaration to the version you suggested and I'm still getting the compiler error. I don't believe my problem is the same of the person's question link you posted. I'm always using NXSoundType as a variable type declaration, not "enum NXSoundType" or mixing approaches. Thanks for the reply anyway.